# Small icons in ParaView, Surface pro 6 Linux

Tags: linux, paraview, surface-pro

I am new to Linux. I am running Linux in surface pro 6, the display resolution and everything is good except Paraview. I tried to change some settings in ParaView and font size was better now but the icons in the GUI were too small. I came through some posts in the Gitlab, but none of them is clear to a newbie. Can someone help me with this with a clear solution, please?
Thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTxHG.png)

Comment: you may want to just delete this as I answered you already.

Answer (score 0):

By Mathieu Westphal

Bug in Qt, work around is : `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0 ./bin/paraview`

https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/issues/19751